# Calculate year over year increase SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, calculated-columns

Below is my table structure.  I need to calculate rent for length of lease for each properties:

Let's look at PropertyID = 12077:

- Area = 1280
- StartDate = 2023-02-01
- EndDate = 2027-10-31
- BaseRent = 21.53
- RentIncreasePercent = .04 (4 percent)
- IncreaseRepeatMonths = 12 months (NOTE:  First 12 months there won't be any increase)

Since this property lease starts and ends between year 2023 and 2028, I'd like to know (in separate row per year) amount of rent to be collected each year.  This would take percent increase every 12 months (compound rent increase) into consideration.

Example:
21.53 * 1280 would give rent for first 12 months.  However, lease started in February so year 2023 total rent amount would be = ((21.23 * 1280)/12) * 11

For year 2024, first month rent would be = (21.23 * 1280)/12 because rent only increases every 12 months.  For next 11 months of 2024, rent would be ((12.23 * 1.04 * 1280)/12)* 11.

For year 2025, first month rent would be (12.23 * 1.04 *1280)/12).  However, next 11 months of 2025 would be ((12.72 * 1.04 * 1280)/12)*11.  12.72 comes from compound increase.

How would I go about coming up with a view to do this?  Most confusing part to me is not knowing how to accommodate for lease start date when it is not starting on January.

---

```
declare @table table 
(
    PropertyID int,
    area int,
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date,
    BaseRent decimal(12,2),
    RentIncreaseBasis varchar(30),
    RentIncreasePercent decimal(5,2),
    IncreaseRepeatMonths int

)

insert @table values (12076,    5627,   '2024-01-01',   '2028-12-31',   '16.52',    '% Increase',   0.03, 12)
insert @table values (12077,    1280,   '2023-02-01',   '2027-10-31',   '21.53',    '% Increase',   0.04, 12)
insert @table values (12078,    1000,   '2017-03-01',   '2025-11-30',   '23.52',    '% Increase',   0.01, 12)
insert @table values (12079,    2000,   '2020-02-01',   '2024-09-30',   '15.57',    '% Increase',   0.05, 12)
insert @table values (12080,    3000,   '2018-05-01',   '2020-08-31',   '18.58',    '% Increase',   0.04, 12)
insert @table values (12081,    4000,   '2019-08-01',   '2020-12-31',   '22.56',    '% Increase',   0.03, 12)
insert @table values (12082,    5000,   '2017-02-01',   '2028-03-31',   '19.53',    '% Increase',   0.02, 12)

select * from @table
```

Comment: is your intention to do it in pure sql (no t-sql) ?

Comment: I think what you'll need to do is explode your date range into a set of months with the calendar year and 'lease' year.  So your start date is month 2, calendar year 2023, lease year 0.  Next row month 3, cal yr 2023, lease yr 0.  Row 12 is month 1 (Jan,) cal yr 2024, lease yr 0, row 13 is month 2, cal yr 2024, lease yr 1.
Then you should have the data you need to separate the calendar and 'lease' months used as a multiplier for your rent increase.

Comment: @SmartDumb  I sort of need it in a view to plug it into another stored procedure logic.  However, if performance is there t-sql works as well.  At the end of the day, data is used in a much complex ssrs report.

Comment: @beth  Let me try this and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use a calendar table which containts all the months from your table.
I hope my example will work in SQL 2008.

```
-- here is your code

-- the calendar table
DECLARE @MonthCalendar table(
  [Month] date PRIMARY KEY
)

DECLARE @MinDate date,@MaxDate date

-- get min and max date
SELECT
  @MinDate=MIN(StartDate),
  @MaxDate=MAX(EndDate)
FROM @table

-- fill the calendar table
;WITH monthCTE AS(
  SELECT CAST(@MinDate AS date) [Month]

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,[Month])
  FROM monthCTE
  WHERE [Month]<@MaxDate
)
INSERT @MonthCalendar([Month])
SELECT [Month]
FROM monthCTE
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);

-- final query
SELECT
  *,
  (BaseRent*Area*(1+RentIncreasePercent*IncreaseCount))/12 MonthRentAmount,
  (1+RentIncreasePercent*IncreaseCount) TotalPercent
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t.PropertyID ORDER BY m.[Month])-1)/12 IncreaseCount
    FROM @table t
    JOIN @MonthCalendar m ON m.[Month] BETWEEN t.StartDate AND t.EndDate
    --WHERE t.PropertyID=12077
  ) q

-- query for total amounts by PropertyIDs and Years
SELECT
  PropertyID,
  YEAR(StartDate) [Year],
  SUM((BaseRent*Area*(1+RentIncreasePercent*IncreaseCount))/12) YearRentAmount
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t.PropertyID ORDER BY m.[Month])-1)/12 IncreaseCount
    FROM @table t
    JOIN @MonthCalendar m ON m.[Month] BETWEEN t.StartDate AND t.EndDate
    --WHERE t.PropertyID=12077
  ) q
GROUP BY PropertyID,YEAR(StartDate)
ORDER BY PropertyID,[Year]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I only had to update YearRentAmount formula.  What you have isn't calculating compound rate.

Comment: Here's the formula: (BaseRent * Area * (Power(cast(1 + RentIncreasePercent as float) ,IncreaseCount)))/12